# Is there a way to get people name in calculated column in MS LISTS?

Tags: list, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I am working on a Leave Tracker in MS LISTS, where in the Calendar view I want the Proxy name to be displayed.
I have searched more than 100 Links and I couldn't the answer.

Do we have any workaround for it?

Thanks for the answer in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my research, the **“Person Or Group” column** is not supported in the SharePoint Calculated column

SharePoint Calculated column supports the following types of columns:

- Single line of text
- Choice (menu to choose from) | Single Selection
- Number (1, 1.0, 100)
- Currency ($, ¥, €)
- Date and Time
- Yes/No (checkbox)
- Calculated (calculation based on other columns)
- Task Outcome
- External Data
- Content-Type Columns

We recommend that you can create a **Single line of text column** to fill in the Proxy Name.

[image]

Then, you can create a **Calculated column** which concatenates the Title, and Proxy Name(Single line of text) columns,

[image]

Modify the Calendar view and change the **"Month View Title"** column to your new Calculated column.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is the value in the `Name Text` column getting into the `Proxy Name` column?

Comment: @user1063287, I believe its done manually !

Comment: @user1063287 or by using a flow